# Dot product with huge vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

I am facing the following problem: I have a system of 160000 linear equations with 160000 variables. I am going to write two programs on conjugate gradient method and steepest descent method to solve it. The matrix is block tridiagonal with only 5 non zero diagonals, thus it's not necessary to create and store the matrix. But I am having the following problem: when I go to the iterarion stepe, there must be dot product of vectors involved. I have tried the following commands: dot(u,v), u'*v, which are commonly used. But when I run the program, MATLAB told me the data size is too large for the memory.

To resolve this problem, I tried to decompose the huge vector into sparse vectors with small support, then calculate the dot products of small vectors and finally glue them together. But it seems that this method is more complicated and not very efficient, and it is easy (especially for beginners like me) to make mistakes. I wonder if there're any more efficient ways to deal with this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try making the matrix `sparse` to allow MATLAB to take advantage of this and efficiently solve the system.